# Custom Fields in Doctrine MongoDB Document

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I have a specific requirement in a project that requires the use of `MongoDB Collection`, that contains `Documents` with different field sets.

For example, these two `Documents` are in the same Collection. The `name` and `foo` fields are mandatory.

```
{ 'name': 'scott', 'foo': 'abc123' }
{ 'name': 'jack' , 'foo': 'def456', 'bar': 'baz' }
```

Using Doctrine MongoDB ODM, the `Document` fields would be specified in a `Document` class.

As for now, I have my `Document` class extending the following `BaseDocument` and created a custom listener for `PostPersist` event, to update the persisted `Document` with the custom fields.

`BaseDocument` class:

```
class BaseDocument
{
    protected $customFields;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->customFields = array();
    }

    public function setCustomField($name, $value)
    {
        if (\property_exists($this, $name)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Object property '$name' exists, can't be assigned to a custom field");
        }
        $this->customFields[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function getCustomField($name)
    {
        if (\array_key_exists($name, $this->customFields)) {
            return $this->customFields[$name];
        }

        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Custom field '$name' does not exists");
    }

    public function getCustomFields()
    {
        return $this->customFields;
    }
}
```

`postPersist` listener:

```
class CustomFieldListener
{
    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {   
        $dm = $args->getDocumentManager();
        $document = $args->getDocument();

        $collection = $dm->getDocumentCollection(\get_class($document));
        $criteria = array('_id' => new \MongoID($document->getId()));
        $mongoDoc = $collection->findOne($criteria);
        $mongoDoc = \array_merge($mongoDoc, $document->getCustomFields());;
        $collection->update($criteria, $mongoDoc);
    } 
}
```

The current solution is not elegant at all, and requires both `insert` and `update` calls to insert a single `Document`. What is the better way to inject custom fields into the `Document` when persisting, reading & updating?

Comment: Have you considered Inheritance Mapping? http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Comment: @mahok I don't see how it can be done using that. Perhaps you could provide an example?

Comment: You can have a BaseDocument with common properties and then have multiple documents inheriting from that class with their own properties, e.g. a BarDocument with bar-property. This way you don't have to resort to using magic like in `getCustomField()`